# Another 3D plot question- good and ugly but no bad-

Tags: plotting

I have the following code with the intention to have a 3D  plot:

```
f0[y_] :=1/(E^((1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
f1[y_] :=1/(E^((-1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])

l[y_] :=f1[y]/f0[y]

t[x_] :=NIntegrate[f1[y]^x*f0[y]^(1 - x), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

epsilon0[x_] :=-Log[t[x]] + (x*NIntegrate[l[y]^x*f0[y]*Log[l[y]], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}])/t[x]

epsilon1[x_] :=-Log[t[x]] + ((-1 + x)*NIntegrate[l[y]^x*f0[y]*Log[l[y]], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}])/t[x]

Plot[epsilon0[x], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[epsilon1[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I have the following figures

[image]! 
[image]!

**Good:**

> However I want to have a single graph probably a 3D plot for epsilon0, epsilon1 and $x$

For example when $x=0.2$ we have $\epsilon_0=0.08$ and $\epsilon_1=1.28$ if I change $x\in[0,1]$ I will get a pair $(\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1)$ for each $x$ and this should be representable in 3D at least as points. But I couldt do it.

**Ugly:**

> What is the 3D figure if we allow **any** pair of continuous densities $f_0$ and $f_1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which have $D(f_0,f_1)=2$ and $D(f_1,f_0)=2$ where $D$ is the relative entropy or KL divergence?

Comment: Why not `ParametricPlot[{epsilon0[x], epsilon1[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks honestly i didnt know it. Right now I plotted and it seems also nice. But the $x$ information is lost. I was thinking $x$ at the $z$ axis and the corresponding $(\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1)$ as a point on the 3d plane.

Comment: Then you can do `ParametricPlot3D[{x, epsilon0[x], epsilon1[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]`. I am confused because you picked the tag which answers your question.

Comment: @b.gatessucks ahahaha thats true!

Comment: Do we really need a [tag:parametricplot3d] tag? As it seems it was created here.

Comment: @Silvia probably you are right.

Comment: @b.gatessucks It appears that your solution answered that question, would you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detail : your functions are simple enough that the integrals can actually be evaluated analytically.

```
t2[x_] = Integrate[f1[y]^x*f0[y]^(1 - x), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* E^(2 (-1 + x) x) *)

epsilon02[x_] = -Log[t2[x]] + 
    (x*Integrate[l[y]^x*f0[y]*Log[l[y]], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]) / t2[x]
(* 2 x (-1 + 2 x) - Log[E^(2 (-1 + x) x)] *)

epsilon12[x_] = -Log[t2[x]] + 
  ((-1 + x) * Integrate[l[y]^x*f0[y]*Log[l[y]], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]) / t2[x]
(* 2 (-1 + x) (-1 + 2 x) - Log[E^(2 (-1 + x) x)] *)

Simplify[epsilon02[x], Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 1}]
(* 2 x^2 *)

Simplify[epsilon12[x], Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 1}]
(* 2 (-1 + x)^2 *)

ParametricPlot3D[{epsilon02[x], epsilon12[x], x}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]